# Laravel 4 delete a value from a multidimensional session array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there any better way to delete a value from this kind of array?

```
$cart = Session::get('cart):
dd($cart);
// Returns this..
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
    'border_id' => string '11' (length=2)
    'process' => string '516.jpg' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'border_id' => string '10' (length=2)
      'process' => string '500.jpg' (length=7)
```

I got this so far. It works but there must be an easier way.

```
// Look for value: 
$process = 516.jpg;
//Search and compare items
$cart = Session::get('cart');
foreach($cart as $key =>$value){
if ($value['process']==$process) {  
// Get Index value
    $image = $key;  }
// Delete Value that as a key of 0
unset($cart[$image]);
Session::forget('cart');
Session::put('cart', $cart);
// Results
dd($cart);
 2 => 
array (size=2)
'border_id' => string '10' (length=2)
'process' => string '500.jpg' (length=7)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the cart to be able to search trough the process value for each entry, but it can be shortened a bit. `Session::forget()` is as far as I know able to delete items in an array by using dot annotation.

```
Session::forget('cart.' . $id);
```

This is how I would do it:

```
$process = '500.jpg';

foreach (Session::get('cart', []) as $id => $entries) {
    if ($entries['process'] === $process) {
        Session::forget('cart.' . $id);
        break; // stop loop
    }
}

dd(Session::get('cart'));
```